# Java array, NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I declared two cards:

```
Card card1 = new Card('3', Card.Suit.clubs);
Card card2 = new Card('T', Card.Suit.diamonds);
```

This works:

```
Hand hand1 = new Hand();

hand1.takeCard(card1);
```

But why does this not work? It gives me a NullPointerException on second line:

```
Hand[] hand = new Hand[2];

hand[0].takeCard(card2);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are declaring an array of 2 hands. This is just setting up the array. You then need to instantiate the hand objects inside the array.

Say

```
hand[0] = new Hand(); 
hand[1] = new Hand();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to go though this...
I will clear your concepts...
Please refer Java tutorials as and when possible.. its helpful

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html