# Java Nullpoint Exception

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and store the row entries into an object using the following code:

```
package eclipsePackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MainProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner file=null;
                try{ 
                    file=new Scanner(new File("notes.txt"));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("unable to open the file");
                }
                    Ages arr[]=new Ages[5];
                    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
                            arr[i].readData(file);
                    }
                    file.close();
                    System.out.println("Name"+"\t"+"Age"+"\t"+"Year of Birth");
                    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                        arr[i].outputData();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The method that reads the file is in a class called Ages.
But I'm getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eclipsePackage.MainProg.main(MainProg.java:16)
Can someone help me fix it

Comment: On second thought, Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170192/java-array-nullpointerexception

Comment: You haven't created an Ages object before asking it to readData. Fix that. (Creating the array only gives you a place to store references to the objects and fills it with nulls; you need to `new` the objects themselves as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, you allocate an array, but not the individual element objects of the array. When you then attempt to access arr[i], the elements are null.

```
 Ages arr[]=new Ages[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
             arr[i].readData(file); // ERROR here.
     }
```

Change to:

```
 Ages arr[]=new Ages[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
             arr[i] = new Ages(); //or whatever your constructor should be.
             arr[i].readData(file); 
     }
```

This is a common newbie mistake.  Read about [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your array like this:

```
Ages arr[]=new Ages[5];
```

it creates an array of five elements, but each of them has a `null` value. You need to populate each slot before you use it. So maybe something like this (depending on how the `Ages` class is declared):

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
    arr[i] = new Ages();
    arr[i].readData(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot 
that makes so much more sense

Answer (score 0):

See your code:

```
     Ages arr[]=new Ages[5];
```

It tells the compiler that you are going to use an array named `arr`. It holds objects of the class `Ages`. Then you intialize the array by `new Ages[5]`. It means memory for 5 `Ages` objects is allocated next to each other.
But the 5 objects are not initialized still. Each of the 5 elements in the array has null value.
By calling `arr[i].readData(file);`
You are creating room for `null pointer Exception`.

You should add

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    arr[i]=new Ages()//or call any constructor inside Ages
    arr[i].readData(file)//No exception here
}
```