# java.lang.NullPointerException when passing a boolean through an array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'm trying to make a game for my Java class, but I keep getting a NPE. I know that it means one of the variables being passed is a null, but I have no idea where. I have checked all variables involved. I believe it may be an issue with initializing the arrays, but I'm still not seeing what I've done wrong. I've checked around stack overflow and I have seen NPEs due to various reasons, but I can't find a solution that works on mine.

```
public class Inventory{
public int gold = 0;
private Item[] itemListArray = new Item[30];
private JButton[] itemButtonArray = new JButton[30];
private JButton buttonBack = new JButton("Back");
private static final String HOME = "Home";
public Inventory() {
    for(int i = 1;i < 31; i++)
    {
        itemListArray[i].emptySlot = true; //Here is where the NPE hits
    }
}}
```

That is where the NPE calls for the error

```
public class Item {
protected String name = "";
protected int def = 0;
protected int stack = 100;
protected boolean stackable = false;
protected boolean consume = false;
boolean emptySlot = true;
protected ImageIcon icon;
public Item(){

}
public boolean isArmor()
{
    if(def >= 1)
    {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
public boolean isConsumable()
{
    if(consume = true)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(emptySlot = true)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration of Item.

Please Answer soon to my issue, I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: There is *exactly one reason* for an NPE. The thing you're trying to use is `null`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java array, NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170192/java-array-nullpointerexception) or any of the other 100 times this has been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't sufficient for you to instantiate your array, you must also populate it with objects. Otherwise each index contains null by default.

```
private Item[] itemListArray = new Item[30];
for (int i = 0; i < itemListArray.length; i++) {
    itemListArray[i] = new Item();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Item[] itemListArray = new Item[30];
```

This code just creates an array that contains `null` values, you need to initializes each individual value in the array.

```
for(int i = 1;i < 31; i++)
{
    itemListArray[i].emptySlot = true; //Here is where the NPE hits
}
```

And this cycle will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` later because in Java valid array indexes start from 0 and go to array.length-1 (0 to 29 in your case), while this code will try to access `itemListArray[ 30 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate your array with `private Item[] itemListArray = new Item[30];` which creates an array of type Item with 30 null entries.

When you call `itemListArray[i].emptySlot` in your loop in the constructor you are accessing a variable from a null object.

You will have to instantiate any Item objects in your array in the loop in your constructor (or elsewhere) before you can access any variables or invoke any methods from them.

Also your `for` loop is skipping the first element. The first element in Java has an index of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may haven't understand initialization in java.you just initialize a array ,but it haven't refer to the real object.

code like this will help:

```
for(int i = 1;i < 31; i++){   
        Item item = new Item();
        item.emptySlot = true;
        itemListArray[i] = item; //Here is where the NPE hits
}
```

try to use a constructor in Item class is much better,hope it work.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of objects defaults all of them to null. You need to put an object into each element of the array to get rid of this problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemListArray.length; i++) {
    itemListArray[i] = new Item();
}

for (int j = 0; j < itemButtonArray.length; j++) {
    itemButtonArray[j] = new JButton();
}
```